# How is a proc object preserved under `&`-`&` roundtrip?

Tags: ruby, proc

When I splat an array with `*` when passing it to a method, then reconstruct an array from it with `*` within the method, the identity of the array is not preserved:

```
a = []
a.object_id # => 69846339548760
def bar *a; a.object_id end
bar(*a) # => 69846339537540
```

However, when I turn a proc into a block with `&` when passing it to a method, then reconstruct a proc from the block with `&` within the method, the identity of the proc seems to be preserved:

```
pr = ->{}
pr.object_id # => 69846339666160
def foo &pr; pr.object_id end
foo(&pr) # => 69846339666160
```

How is the proc object preserved? Isn't it lost when it is converted to a block? Is this a guaranteed behaviour?

Comment: Even more: `def baz ; puts Proc.new.object_id end ; p = ->{} ; p.object_id #⇒ 9708320 ; baz &p ; #⇒ 9708320`

Comment: @mudasobwa That is due to a special syntax convention. When you create a proc without a block within a method, it refers to the proc passed to the method.

Comment: I know, thank you. I meant that `Proc.new` is in fact _not a constructor_.

Comment: @mudasobwa Now I see your point.

Comment: Arent't `Proc` instances immutable?  Why a new instance to be created when it is passed as parameter to method?

Comment: @WandMaker What is passed is not a proc, but a block.

Comment: @sawa - `pr.class` says `Proc` both inside and outside the function.  I think Ruby uses `Proc` internally for all blocks.

Comment: @WandMaker The moment `pr` is accepted by the method, it has already become a proc. If it were a block, it is not an object, and you could not call any method on it. Your second sentence may be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby VM is a stackmachine. When calling a function, it puts all its arguments (including `self`) onto the stack and then calls.

How array splat works - it takes array contents and puts it onto the stack, then calls function:

```
> puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile("a = []; func *a").disasm
== disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:<compiled>@<compiled>>==========
local table (size: 2, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1, kw: -1@-1, kwrest: -1])
[ 2] a          
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 newarray         0
0004 setlocal_OP__WC__0 2
0006 putself          
0007 getlocal_OP__WC__0 2
0009 splatarray       false
0011 opt_send_without_block <callinfo!mid:func, argc:1, ARGS_SPLAT|FCALL>
0013 leave
```

When passing proc as a block, similar thing happens, but ruby does not have to unwrap proc, it is already a proc.

**Added:** as per RubySpec's https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/proc/block_pass_spec.rb

```
def revivify; Proc.new; end

it "remains the same object if re-vivified by the target method" do
  p = Proc.new {}
  p2 = revivify(&p)
  p.object_id.should == p2.object_id
  p.should == p2
end
```

this is somewhat standardized behavior, so at least should be followed by Rubinius and jRuby

Comment: So does this mean the answer to this question depends on whether you're using MRI, JRuby, Rubinius, etc?

Comment: @JoshRumbut rubyspec defines this behaviour, so it should be the same